# can escaping ruin my http GET request?

Tags: java, http, url, escaping, webresource

I try to trigger an http GET request

It should be as follows:

`https://www.my_service.com/myRequest?from=x%3A34.78104114532471+y%3A31.243920719573723&to=x%3A34.77901339530945+y%3A31.242416368424312&`

I wrote this code

```
            webResource.accept("application/json");

            ClientResponse response = webResource.path("myRequest")
                    .queryParam("from", "x%3A34.78104114532471+y%3A31.243920719573723")
                    .queryParam("to", "x%3A34.77901339530945+y%3A31.242416368424312")
.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                    .get(ClientResponse.class);

            if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + response.getStatus());
            }
```

which generates this url:

`https://www.my_service.com/myRequest?from=x%3A34.78104114532471+y%3A31.243920719573723&to=x%3A34.77901339530945+y%3A31.242416368424312&`

but this returns 404 error.

I have tried the two urls in the browser.
The only difference is `+` replaced by `%2B`

`+` works for me but `%2B` doesn't.

how can i make the code not replace `+` with `%2B`?

Answer (score 0):

Strangely I had to replace + with space:

```
   .queryParam("from", "x%3A34.78104114532471 y%3A31.243920719573723")
   .queryParam("to", "x%3A34.77901339530945 y%3A31.242416368424312")
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense, doesn't it? You're using an API which does the necessary escaping internally. Maybe you just don't know the rules---`+` is the escape char for space in URLs.

Comment: For that matter, I suggest you use the plain `:` character instead of `%3A` and get that escaped internally as well. Would make your code much easier on the eye.